# ABI-encoding in Nethereum of a struct that contains a bytes-array (variable size)

Tags: abi, nethereum, abiencoderv2

I have a custom struct defined in solidity. When calling the decode-function of the contract, I want to decode an encoded MyStruct (in bytes).

This works perfectly as long as a previous defined MyStruct was encoded via `abi.encode(...)` in solidity.

```
pragma solidity ^0.8.19;
pragma abicoder v2;

struct MyStruct {
    address from;
    address to;
    bytes data; // length of bytes-array is dynamic
}

contract TestContract {
    function encode() public pure returns (bytes memory encoded) {
        encoded = abi.encode(MyStruct({
            from: 0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48,
            to: 0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F,
            data: hex"00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"
        }));
    }

    function decode(bytes calldata encoded) public pure {
        MyStruct memory myStruct = abi.decode(encoded, (MyStruct));
    }
}
```

But how can I do that with Nethereum?

The encoder of solidity gives me the following hex-string with the example below:

```
0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000020000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00000000000000000000000000000000
```

When encoding with Nethereum, I got a slighty different result, which can't be decoded in the SmartContract.

```
0x000000000000000000000000a0b86991c6218b36c1d19d4a2e9eb0ce3606eb480000000000000000000000006b175474e89094c44da98b954eedeac495271d0f0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000060000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001000112233445566778899aabbccddeeff00000000000000000000000000000000
```

```
ABIEncode abiEncode = new ABIEncode();

ABIValue[] abiValues = new ABIValue[] {
    new ABIValue("address", "0xA0b86991c6218b36c1d19D4a2e9Eb0cE3606eB48"),
    new ABIValue("address", "0x6B175474E89094C44Da98b954EedeAC495271d0F"),
    new ABIValue("bytes", Convert.FromHexString("00112233445566778899aabbccddeeff"))
};

byte[] abiValuesEnconded = abiEncode.GetABIEncoded(abiValues);
string result = "0x" + Convert.ToHexString(abiValuesEnconded).ToLowerInvariant();
```